Power Bi Measure for Average of Distinct Values
I am trying to write a measure in Power Bi to get the average of two distinct values.
I have attached my example,
I need to answer to show as $4053.5 which is the average of those two IDs.

Avg Cost:=AVERAGE(table1[Cost])  ?
You may need CALCULATE to modify your evaluation context, but can't tell without further details.

maybe you can try this to create a measure
MEASURE =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Cost] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
    / CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[ID] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )


